# ng-model doesn't update on continuous removal of characters in a input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-digest

We have problem with the ng-model not updating correctly or atleast we think. Our problem seems to be, that our ng-model doesn't update itself when we continuously remove characters from a input field.

We have a two inputfields one of those is a tinyMCE textarea.

```
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error has-feedback': vacancyForm.inputDescription.$touched && vacancyForm.inputDescription.$invalid}">
          <label for="inputDescription">{{ 'Vacancy.Description' | translate }}</label>
          <textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" ng-model="vacancy.description" ng-change="vm.pasteDescriptionTextInSummary()" ng-model="tinymceModel" class="form-control" required rows="8"></textarea>
          <input type="hidden" ng-model="vacancy.description" name="inputDescription">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true" ng-show="vacancyForm.inputDescription.$touched && vacancyForm.inputDescription.$invalid"></span>
          <span class="help-block text-danger" ng-show="vacancyForm.inputDescription.$touched && vacancyForm.inputDescription.$invalid">{{ 'Vacancy.Description.Alert' | translate }}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error has-feedback': vacancyForm.inputSummary.$touched && vacancyForm.inputSummary.$invalid}">
          <label for="inputSummary">{{ 'Vacancy.Summary' | translate }} <small>{{300 - vacancy.summary.length}} {{ 'Vacancy.Characters' | translate }}</small></label>
          <textarea ng-model="vacancy.summary" minlength="1" maxlength="300" name="inputSummary" class="form-control" required rows="2"></textarea>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true" ng-show="vacancyForm.inputSummary.$touched && vacancyForm.inputSummary.$invalid"></span>
          <span class="help-block text-danger" ng-show="vacancyForm.inputSummary.$touched && vacancyForm.inputSummary.$invalid">{{ 'Vacancy.Summary.Alert' | translate }}</span>
        </div>
```

In the code block above we want the vacancy.summary model to be set to the vacancy.description model. We use the javascript function below which is triggered by a ng-change.

```
vm.pasteDescriptionTextInSummary = function(e) {
    var desc = $scope.vacancy.description;
    if (desc) {
        desc = desc.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '')
            .replace(/&nbsp;/gi, ' ')
            .replace(/&amp;/gi, '&')
            .replace(/&lt;/gi, '<')
            .replace(/&gt;/gi, '>');

        var cutString = '';

        if (desc.length > 300) {
            cutString = desc.substring(0, 300);
            $scope.vacancy.summary = cutString;
        } else {
            $scope.vacancy.summary = desc;
        }
    } else {
        $scope.vacancy.summary = desc;
    }
};
```

The function works like we wanted it to, however like the title says we have issues with continuous removal of characters and it updates in chunks and not per character (digest cycle?). Even when we set the models directly to each other it is still not updating properly even though it doesn't go through the function.

Comment: You have two `ng-moedl` in your first `textarea`. Is it typo?

Comment: guess you rename the controller to vm, try vm.vacancy.summary and remove one of your ng-model